# EF Foreign Key Associations Deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

The picture show relation with two tables in my database;
[image]

Well as you can see there's a field called "DeviceTypeID" in the right side table.

Normally EF adds CompanyTypeID column to the ServiceLaburDefinitions model but it's disappeared last time I updated model from the database.

[image]

I am searching for a solution for a couple of hours but not able to find any solution. Could anyne suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: It's in your navigation properties

Comment: I am aware of that DeviceType is in Navigation Propertites. But the other tables works normal and FK fields exists in their model.

Answer (score -1):

ServiceLaburDefinitions is the depend entity and has the DeviceTypeID foreign key property defined.

So Entity Framework creates a navigation Key under the hood between the 2 tables based on DeviceTypeId key.

You can see for example how a navigation key is created also in the following example between the foreign key and the primary key

[image]

More information about navigation properties can be found [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2042836.aspx?I%20m%20very%20confused%20in%20navigation%20properties%20in%20entity%20framework%20how%20it%20works%20and%20how%20it%20usefull%20)

When you create the model from the database, there is a checkbox marked "Include Foreign Key columns In The Model" - Make sure this is checked.

[image]

Comment: He's asking about why the ID is missing from the generated code when he uses the Database First approach - how does this answer help him?